# How to sync a public subfolder of one repository with another repository?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a software project `foo` on an internal GitLab repository hosted by my company and want to partially publish it as an open source project `baa` on GitHub.

Lets say I put the public part in a folder "public":

```
foo/public
```

and the private parts in a folder "private":

```
foo/private
```

How can I sync the `public` folder with a public GitHub repository `https://github.com/user/new_repository.git` ?

In my wildest dreams I would have:

**a)** An automation pipeline (gitlab-ci.yml) in `foo`, forwarding/syncing each change of the `public` folder to baa

**b)** Allow external users to contribute to `baa` and be somehow able to merge their changes back to `foo`.

**c)** As an alternative to a) have a way to sync only from time to time, after certain requirements are fulfilled (e.g. export control of a new feature).

I saw the git commands

1. git submodule
2. git subtree

and the

3. repository mirroring feature of GitLab:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/

but I am not sure if they are applicable for my use case.

Let' say I would like to use parts of `foo` as submodule in `baa`... how to ensure, that only the folder `public` is considered instead of the whole project?

Maybe my approach is wrong and I should first try to separate the public and private parts to individual projects.

Related questions and articles:

[How to link folder from a git repo to another repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554810/how-to-link-folder-from-a-git-repo-to-another-repo)

[How to mirror a GitLab repository to GitHub using SSH keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76456288/how-to-mirror-a-gitlab-repository-to-github-using-ssh-keys)

https://www.atlassian.com/de/git/tutorials/git-subtree

[How do I git "subtree split" but maintain the full folder hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940679/how-do-i-git-subtree-split-but-maintain-the-full-folder-hierarchy)

Comment: do you need the history on the public repository or you can start from now ?

Comment: I don't need the history.

Comment: create a new repository with the public content, delete the public content and add the newly created repository as a submodule

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-move-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository

Comment: How to add the content of the new submodule while keeping the original folder structure? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76462811/how-to-add-the-content-of-a-git-submodule-directly-in-the-curent-directory-with

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the comments I found the solutions shown below.

- **A** uses `submodule` and is a closer match to **a)** from the question.
- **B** uses `subtree` and is a closer match to **c)** from the question and seems to be less complicated.

## 0. Fill a separate repository with content of public folder

Push content of folder "public" to new repository:

```
cd public    
git init --initial-branch=main    
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/new_repository.git    
git add .    
git commit -m "Initial commit"     
git push -u origin main
```

## A. Use separate repository as submodule "public"

### Integrate submodule

- Delete public folder inside main folder
- Commit main folder (=> apply deletion of public folder)
- Add new repository as a submodule "public":

  git submodule add -b main https://github.com/user/new_repository.git public

  git submodule update --remote

The git submodule add command creates a file .gitmodules containing

```
[submodule "public"]
    path = public
    url = https://github.com/user/new_repository.git
    branch = main
```

- Commit and push main folder

### Fresh Clone

If someone else does a **fresh clone** of the main project, the **recursive** option needs to be used. Otherwise the content of the submodule folder "public" will be empty.

[image]

### Commit change of submodule

If someone changes the content of the submodule, the submodule and the main project need to be committed/pushed separately. This seems to be a disadvantage of the submodule approach.

If I change a file of the submodule, the main project does not recognize that as a change (list of commit dialog will be empty). Once I committed the change using the submodule folder, the main project does recognize a change (new version of submodule). Then the main project needs to be committed, too.

The push dialog of TortoiseGit has the value "On demand" for the "Recurse submodule" option:

[image]

Therefore, at least the push action can be done for both, the main and the submodule project. (If there is a single command to commit and push both, please let me know.)

### Related questions on usage of submodules

[How do I "git clone" a repo, including its submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796927/how-do-i-git-clone-a-repo-including-its-submodules)

[How do I "commit" changes in a git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542910/how-do-i-commit-changes-in-a-git-submodule)

[How to add the content of a git submodule directly in the curent directory, without extra project folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76462811/how-to-add-the-content-of-a-git-submodule-directly-in-the-curent-directory-with)

[git submodule tracking latest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189575/git-submodule-tracking-latest?answertab=active#tab-top)

## B. Use separate repository as subtree "public"

### Include subtree

- Delete public folder inside main folder
- Commit main folder (=> apply deletion of public folder)
- Use subtree command to include files of repository locally

---

```
git subtree add --prefix public https://github.com/user/new_repository.git main --squash
```

- Push main folder (commit is already done by `subtree add` command)

### Fresh Clone

- A fresh clone includes all files of the subtree. In comparison to submodules no extra command or option is required.

### Commit change of subtree

- A change in the subtree is recognized by the parent/main project as normal file change and is committed with the main project by default.
- When committing to the main project, the repository for the subtree is not automatically updated.
- In order to apply the local changes to the subtree repository, use following explicit command:

---

```
git subtree push --prefix public https://github.com/user/new_repository.git main --squash
```

Its possible to introduce an **alias** for the url, so that the over all length of the command gets shorter, using `git add remote`, see https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-subtree

### Pull changes of subtree

```
git subtree pull --prefix public https://github.com/user/new_repository.git main
```

### Related articles on subtree

- https://gist.github.com/SKempin/b7857a6ff6bddb05717cc17a44091202
- https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-subtree