# How to mirror a GitLab repository to GitHub using SSH keys?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

GitLab has a mirror feature:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/

and GitHub does not support simple password authentication. I tried to follow

https://meesvandongen.nl/posts/mirror-gitlab-github

Using the target url

```
ssh://git@github.com:stefaneidelloth/mirror_demo.git
```

and `SSH public key` as authentication method.

However, I get an error

```
Remote mirrors url is blocked: URI is invalid
```

from GitLab.

If I specify the target url

```
https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/mirror_demo.git
```

I am not able to select `SSH public key` as authentication method.

=> What are the right settings to mirror a GitLab project to a GitHub project (without PREMIUM edition of GitLab)?

*Edit*

The second `:` needs to be replaced with a `/`.

Suggested by GitHub:

[image]

Adding `ssh://` prefix is not enough.

Wrong: `ssh://git@github.com:stefaneidelloth/mirror_demo.git`

Still need to replace `:` after github.com:

Right: `ssh://git@github.com/stefaneidelloth/mirror_demo.git`

Then GitLab generates the SSH key for the connection and one needs to copy it to the GitHub project settings (not the user settings), see https://meesvandongen.nl/posts/mirror-gitlab-github

Now I get the next error:

```
13:get remote references: create git ls-remote: exit status 128, stderr: "ssh connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.\n".
```

**a)** Do I need to specify a different port than 22? How? I tried

```
ssh://git@github.com:443/stefaneidelloth/mirror_demo.git
```

but that did not help.

**b)** Do I need to use "Input host keys manually"? What should be specified? I tried to use

SHA256:uNiVztksCsDhcc0u9e8BujQXVUpKZIDTMczCvj3tD2s

from

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints

but that did not help.

**c)** I also tried to generate a GitHub **AccessToken** in the user settings and apply it for the password option of the GitLab Mirror settings. I tried both, `https://` and `git://` urls. No success.

Comment: I tried this too. Couldn't get it to work. I got past the error you're getting once I added the generated SSH key to the GitHub repo as a Deploy token with write access. However, while there are no more errors being shown, the GitHub repo does not get updated and hitting refresh just seems to fail without errors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got this to work after all.

1. Yes, you need to manually edit the git SSH URL, as you have shown:
   `ssh://git@github.com/stefaneidelloth/mirror_demo.git`
2. Select SSH public key as authentication method.
3. Then click mirror repository button
4. Copy the SSH key generated as shown here: https://meesvandongen.nl/posts/mirror-gitlab-github and https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/push.html#set-up-a-push-mirror-from-gitlab-to-github
5. The key then needs to be added as a Deploy Key to the GitHub Repo, which is done from Settings > Deploy Keys (see figure below)
6. Click refresh on the mirror. Note that when I first did this, nothing happened, no errors, but also no update. I did it four times and still nothing happened. Then about 27 minutes later, the update happened.

[image: Deploy Keys]

Comment: Slight addendum to this: you need to set the username of the SSH key to `git` on the GitLab, in the section below 'Authentication Method'. Nothing else will work!

(I don't know if it's changed since your or Mees's posts because neither of you mentioned it, but it's there now and stumped me for a while.)

Comment: Thanks.  Also manually retrieve the host key by pushing that button.  It's crazy how that screen lets you save settings that can't possibly succeed. As of: 16.8.1-ce.0 .

Answer (score 3):

"ssh connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out" suggests that something is blocking port 22 for github.com - perhaps a proxy or firewall. GitHub has a separate hostname (not `github.com`) for handling SSH traffic over a rarely-blocked port; your URL for that would need to be `ssh://git@ssh.github.com:443/stefaneidelloth/mirror_demo.git`.

Comment: Thank you @geoidesic and **@jim-redmond**