# How to add the content of a git submodule directly in the curent directory, without extra project folder?

Tags: git

Lets assume that I extracted a sub folder "public" to a new repository "my_public_repository".
Now I want to replace the public folder in the original project with the content of the new submodule (= I want to keep the original folder structure but change the origin).

I tried `git submodule add https://github.com/user/my_public_repository`.

Instead of the wanted folder strurcture

```
project
  + public
```

I got

```
project
  + my_public_repository
    + public
```

I tried to specify the target directory for `git submodule add` as the current directory with `.` or `/`. However, that did not work.

=> How can I directly add the content of the submodule, without extra folder for the project name?

Related question:

[How to sync a public subfolder of one repository with another repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76454282/how-to-sync-a-public-subfolder-of-one-repository-with-another-repository/76462303#76462303)

Answer (score 0):

Worked around the issue, by not pushing the whole public folder but only its content to the new repository.